# Prevent default context menu in kinetic JS stage rightclick?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, contextmenu, kineticjs

I need to disable the context menu in kinetic js on click of stage. I have tried everything like `event.preventDefault()`, `cancelbubble`, `event.stopPropagation() return false`, but nothing works..

Here is an example in jsfiddle.. Wat change needs to be done to prevent default context menu from displaying

```
stage.on('click',stageClicked,true);
function stageClicked(event){
   if(event.button==2){
       event.cancelBubble = true;
       event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();

       return false;
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xPbgf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer removes the context menu, but does not allow @user2045685 to select the `event.targetNode` on right click.

@user2045685 states in his comments that he found a workaround by using the `getAllIntersection` method, but I **urge** you not to use that alternative as that's not what it was intended for, the `getAllIntersection` method has very **poor** performance, and using `event.targetNode` works just fine.

> getAllIntersections(pos)
>
> get all shapes that intersect a point. **Note: because this method must clear a temporarycanvas and redraw every shape inside the container, it should only be used for special sitations because it performs very poorly. Please use the Kinetic.Stage#getIntersection method if at all possiblebecause it performs much better**

Source: [Kinetic.Container#getAllIntersections](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#getAllIntersections)

Instead, you can bind an event listener to your `div#container` and call `event.preventDefault()` to disable the context menu.

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

You also need to add a "background rectangle" with the width and height of your stage, so that the layer can detect your clicks. That's why in @Brandon Boone's answer above he stated that the "on doesn't seem to do anything." for the stage. KineticJS expects a node to listen for events, so if you don't add a "transparent background", then `stage.on("click")` will only fire when you right click the green rectangle (but not the rest of the stage).

```
var bg = new Kinetic.Rect({
  width: stage.getWidth(),
  height: stage.getHeight()
});

// add bg first as your transparent background
layer.add(bg);
// add the shape to the layer
layer.add(rect);
```

Now you can use your `stage.on('click', stgClicked)` function with no problems and call `event.targetNode` inside your `stgClicked` function.

```
function stgClicked(event) {
  if (event.button == 2) {
     alert('rightclick');
     var node = event.targetNode;
     console.log(node);
  }
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/CuvMW/)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to find the canvas reference within the stage object and attach the `contextmenu` event directly to it as passing it into `on` doesn't seem to do anything.

Try this:

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xPbgf/7/)**</kbd>

```
var canvas = stage.content.childNodes[0]; 
if (canvas.addEventListener) {
    canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', stgClicked, false); 
} else if (canvas.attachEvent)  {
    canvas.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', stgClicked);
}
```

---

If you want the targetNode, just check for it within the native javaScript event.

```
function stgClicked(event){
    var targetNode;
    if (event.srcElement)  targetNode = event.srcElement;
    else if (event.target) targetNode = event.target;

    alert(targetNode.nodeName);
}
```

Comment: but this wont give me the kinetic js event back to my stgClicked function where in I will use the event.targetNode to get the exact shape on which it was right clicked...

Comment: I meant the target node as the kinetic Shape which am clicking.. In this case if I right click on rectangle over it.. i should get the target node as the Kinetic.Rect object with all its properties which I can access.. Any ways I found an another way by passing the event to getAllIntersection method of kinetic js to get the shapes below current mouse position.. but that is not so accurate...

Comment: Please don't use the getAllIntersection method to select your targetNode! See my answer below.